# Convert nested object type recursively to modify all value types

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to be able convert an arbitrary interface definition that keeps the hierarchy and keys intact, but changes all value types to a new one.

## Example

Source object:

```
export interface MyObject {
  id: string
  created: Date
  deleted?: boolean
  data: {
    history: string[]
  }
  meta?: {
    aggregation: {
      min: number
      max: number
    }
  }
}
```

Target object replaced all non-Record types to `string`:

```
export interface MyObject {
  id: string
  created: string
  deleted?: string
  data: {
    history: string
  }
  meta?: {
    aggregation: {
      min: string
      max: string
    }
  }
}
```

## What I tried

```
type ConvertToStringValue<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Record<string, unknown> ? Record<K, ConvertToStringValue<T[K]>> : string
}
let convertedMyObject: ConvertToStringValue<MyObject>
```

My Reasoning:

- For each key we check if the value is a Record or not.
- If yes, we define a Record and compute the value recursively
- If no the value needs to be a string

It doesn't work though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, just don't wrap the transformed value into another record. Return it directly:

```
type ConvertToStringValue<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Record<string, unknown> | undefined ? ConvertToStringValue<T[K]> : string
}
```

This seems to give the inference you want:

```
declare let convertedMyObject: ConvertToStringValue<MyObject>;
convertedMyObject.id // string
convertedMyObject.created // string
convertedMyObject.deleted // string | undefined
convertedMyObject.data.history // string
convertedMyObject.data.min // string
convertedMyObject.meta.aggregation.min // Error: Object is possibly undefined
convertedMyObject.meta?.aggregation.min // string | undefined
```

Comment: Found a typo in my initial question and corrected it. Does it also work for `convertedMyObject.meta.aggregation.min`? Because for me, it doesn't,

Comment: I see that it missed that case because `meta` is optional, so it includes `undefined` it it's value type. Well `undefined` does not extend `Record<string, unknown>` so it was reducing that field to be type `string` instead of recursing. To correct it, all you need to do is include `undefined` in along with `Record`... I have edited the answer to be just so.